# How to add external folders in JBoss 6 classpath

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-7, jboss6.x

We are migrating a web application from websphere to jboss 6.

In WebSphere we configure a folder under classpath [Application Servers > Server > Process Definition > Java Virtual Machine > Classpath].

/opt/folder1
/opt/location1/folder2

With this configuration we were able to read all configuration files inside folder. For example,

/opt/folder1/config1.xml 
/opt/folder1/config1.xml 
/opt/location1/folder2/config3.xml

We are trying to find where in JBoss we can specify these settings. To be specific we want to configure folder paths in JBoss server so that all files under it will be available to application through classpath.

Please help.

-Regards
Ajay

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that jboss is using tomcat as servlet container.

If so, look for a file named **catalina.properties**.

You'll find entries like **common.loader**, **shared.loader** ...

You can add your path entries there and they should be appended to the CLASSPATH.